# How to find patterns in text spanning multiple lines?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I wank to look for indexed array elements that are grouped in collections (comma separated) and the search should result in something like this (see the file data example below) -

```
[    'foo[0]',     'foo[1]',     'foo[2]', ...,     'foo[10]']
['foobar0[0]', 'foobar0[1]', 'foobar0[2]'  ..., 'foobar0[98]']
[    'bas[0]',     'bas[1]',     'bas[2]'  ...,     'bas[99]']
```

I have a text file where these appear as a "collection" that span over multiple lines and the collections are grouped by {..} (as shown below) -

```
{foo[0], foo[1], foo[2], foo[3]...\n
foo[10]}, {fooba0[0], foobar0[1], foobar0[2],....\n
foobar0[98], foobar0[99]}, {bas[0], bas[1], bas[2]...\n
bas[99]}
```

The general expression I am using to search the array elements is -

```
re.findall('[a-z][A-Z]+[0-9]+\[[0-9]+\]', <list item>)
```

In `yacc` this would translate to something like -

```
array_element_token:     [a-z][A-Z]+[0-9]+\[[0-9]+\]
array_items_continued:   array_items_continued             |
                         array_element_token ',' 
arrays_items:            '{' array_items_continued array_element_token '},'
```

Build I am not sure how to create the recursive rule using python regular expressions.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/Be9qhy

Comment: Thanks! This appears to work! Can you explain r""" <string>""? What does that do?

Comment: That is your string example. Triple quotes help specify multiline strings in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re

s = r"""{foo[0], foo[1], foo[2], foo[3]...\n
foo[10]}, {fooba0[0], foobar0[1], foobar0[2],....\n
foobar0[98], foobar0[99]}, {bas[0], bas[1], bas[2]...\n
bas[99]}"""
results = []
matches = re.findall(r'{[^{}]*}', s)
for m in matches:
    results.append( re.findall(r'\w+\[\d+]', m) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Be9qhy), results are `[['foo[0]', 'foo[1]', 'foo[2]', 'foo[3]', 'foo[10]'], ['fooba0[0]', 'foobar0[1]', 'foobar0[2]', 'foobar0[98]', 'foobar0[99]'], ['bas[0]', 'bas[1]', 'bas[2]', 'bas[99]']]`.

The `{[^{}]*}` regex extracts all substrings between `{` and `}`, and then `\w+\[\d+]` extracts all substrings that match the following sequences:

- `\w+` - 1+ letters, digits, `_` chars
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `]` - a `]` char.

Comment: Excellent... Many thanks for the detailed and clear explanation!